# Regex to check if all words from a list are in a string (return string if not found)

Tags: regex

My requirements are slightly different in that I need it to return true if ANY words/phrases are NOT found (existing examples return true if all are found).

I would like to use a Regex to check a string to see if all the words/phrases in a list are in the main string.

The tricky thing is that I want it to return a string if **any** of the words from the list are missing.

e.g.
Word/Phrase List

cat

big dog

That big dog and cat went to town.
(Should return nothing as both words found)

The dog and cat went to town.
(should return a string back since "big dog" is not in the string)

I am not too fussed about what is returned (though my preference would be for the not found word/phrase to be returned. Otherwise it can simply return the original string back).

The main requirement is that a string be returned if any of the words from the list are not found.

I have tried something similar to the following:

```
^(?!.*(BIG DOG|CAT)).*$
```

Unfortunately this does not work as it returns the string if all words are missing. I need it to only return if any word/phrase is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be close to desired:

```
^(?!(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bbig\s+dog\b).*)(?=.*\b(big\s+dog|cat)\b).*$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LLnM7e/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/LLnM7e/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: That worked. I simplified as follows and also added (?i) to make case insensitive.Thank you!        ^(?!(?i)(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bbig\? dog\b).*).*$

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt is not so far off, and lookaheads are one way to do this:

```
^(?=.*\bbig dog\b)(?=.*\bcat\b).*$
```

This would only return true if both `big dog` and `cat` are present are standalone terms/words.  Note that you might want to run this in case insensitive mode.  The exact syntax you would use would very depending on your programming language (which you never told us).

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did try this previously. The problem is that I need to it return true if any word is missing (in this case it returns true if all words are found). Is there anyway to negate (I hope that;s the correct term) the results.

Comment: @SanjaySingh My regex is _only_ if _all_ terms are present.  So, if it's _not_ true, then there is one or more missing.  This meets your requirements AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The following context may explain my requirements a bit better. I am trying to use this  in an existing program without changing existing code. The code gets triggered if something is returned by the user entered regex. In this case the requirement is to trigger if any of the phrases are missing. If all the phrases are there then nothing should be returned and therefore the code will not be triggered.

Comment: Again...my pattern detects whether or not all terms are present, so what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hi Tim. I am very grateful for your response. The only problem was that I couldn't use the RegX as it was without having to change code in my software. I needed true to be returned if any term was missing. Your answer gave true if all terms were found. Thank you again for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to check if the one is present and the other should not be present.

```
^(?:(?=.*\bbig dog\b)(?!.*\bcat\b)|(?!.*\bbig dog\b)(?=.*\bcat\b)).+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?=.*\bbig dog\b)` Assert `big dog` is present
  - `(?!.*\bcat\b)` Assert `cat` is not
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!.*\bbig dog\b)` Assert `big dog` is not present
  - `(?=.*\bcat\b)` Assert `cat` is
- `)` Close group
- `.+` Match any char 1+ times to prevent matching an empty string
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FtZ4p3/1)